# refer to object type in object definition

Tags: scala, generics

---

note: The first example works. It shows what I want to get. The second example shows that I'd like declare it without boilerplate but have failed to do so.

---

I just want to get simple thing:

```
trait SelfTest[T <: SelfTest[T]] {_ : T =>
  def get : T = this
}
class Test extends SelfTest[Test]
object Test extends Test
```

but without boilerplate class definition. Something like this:

```
trait SelfTest[T <: SelfTest[T]] {_ : T =>
  def get : T = this
}
object Test extends SelfTest[Test.type]
```

But this way is rejected by scala (`illegal cyclic reference involving object Test`). Is there any magic like `#` sign to denote created object?

Comment: Which version of Scala compiler are you using? The first version of your code works just fine under Scala 2.10.2

Comment: 2.9.2, 2.10.0. I'd like to use the second one. It is shorter and does not create redundant entities. The question is about how to achieve effect of the first example without defining class like it should be in the second

Answer (score 0):

This worked in scala 2.10 console::

```
scala> trait SelfTest[T<:SelfTest[_]] {_: T => def get:T = this }
defined trait SelfTest

scala> class Test extends SelfTest[Test]
defined class Test

scala> case object t extends Test
defined module t

scala> t.get
res1: Test = t
```

Comment: This worked for me either. But the question is about how to eliminate redundant `class` declaration.