# Why I can't create F-bounded object in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, polymorphism

Suppose I have:

```
trait A[AA <: A[AA]]
//or even just `
trait A[AA]
```

This doesn't work:

```
scala> object AAA extends A[AAA.type]
<console>:8: error: illegal cyclic reference involving object AAA
   object AAA extends A[AAA.type]
                        ^
```

But this works:

```
scala> class AAA extends A[AAA]; object AAA extends AAA
defined class AAA
defined module AAA
```

Doing almost (not exactly) same and this works. Any reason?

P.S. And also, what exactly [can I do](https://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/) inside such object to force infinte cycle inside the compiler itself?

Comment: http://blog.originate.com/blog/2014/02/27/types-inside-types-in-scala/, I think this would help. But what problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: Maybe related: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5082

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915353/refer-to-object-type-in-object-definition, but no good answer

Comment: @Governa no problem - my subtypes are just singletons, so it's just a little overhead for me. First link is just introduce to F-bounded polymorphizm, so no much help. Second helped me to find out that it's not only F-Bounded types problem, thanks

Comment: A workaround might be `trait AAA extends A[AAA]; object AAA extends AAA`

Answer (score 2):

As you allude to in your title, the working case `class AAA extends A[AAA]` is an example of [F-bounded polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification), which is a recursive type definition where the definition refers to itself. Recursion is fairly common in types, even the humble [List is recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type); it's fairly well understood territory.

However, `object AAA extends A[AAA.type]` is not a recursive type. Here `AAA` is a *value*, and your declaration asks the compiler to resolve the reference to a value's type while it is being defined, which is not a capability Scala was designed/intended to have.

Comment: `AAA.type` is a type, not value, so I refer to it, so it's F-bounded. just `AAA` is a value only if you use it as a value, let's say `val a = AAA`. By default it's just a definition, that includes *both* type and value.

Comment: Nope. `AAA` is always a value, never a type, when its an object.

Comment: Nope. It's a type when you do `AAA.type`, and, in my case this `AAA.type` is F-bounded, like `type AAAtype <: A[AAAtype]`

Comment: when you're defining an object, type definition comes "for free" (and becomes accessable with `type` **keyword**) and it's, again, F-bounded here as it refers to itself. object's value cannot refer to type, obviously.

Comment: just try `type AAAtype = A[AAAtype]` and you'll get the same error I've got, because that is what's happening. Scala doesn't allow F-bounded type members. it just seems pretty wrong for object's case.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, but you cannot make him drink